# How to select distinct record from dataframe with last timestamp

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql, distinct, spark-streaming

I have dataframe. I need the lastest record from table on the bases of updateTableTimestamp for each Id.
 `df.show()`

```
+--------------------+-----+-----+--------------------+
|         Description| Name| id  |updateTableTimestamp|
+--------------------+-----+-----+--------------------+
|                    | 042F|64185|       1507306990753|
|                    | 042F|64185|       1507306990759|
|Testing             |042MF|  941|       1507306990753|
|                    | 058F| 8770|       1507306990753|
|Testing 3           |083MF|31663|       1507306990759|
|Testing 2           |083MF|31663|       1507306990753|
+--------------------+-----+-----+--------------------+
```

need the output

```
+--------------------+-----+-----+--------------------+
|         Description| Name| id  |updateTableTimestamp|
+--------------------+-----+-----+--------------------+
|                    | 042F|64185|       1507306990759|
|Testing             |042MF|  941|       1507306990753|
|                    | 058F| 8770|       1507306990753|
|Testing 3           |083MF|31663|       1507306990759|
+--------------------+-----+-----+--------------------+
```

I have tried

```
sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM (SELECT *, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY updateTableTimestamp DESC) rank from temptable) tmp where rank = 1")
```

it gives error on Partition. Exception in thread "main" ``` java.lang.RuntimeException: [1.29] failure: ``union'' expected but ```(' found`I am using spark 1.6.2

Comment: "it gives error" - what's the error?

Comment: Try `where tmp.rank = 1` or maybe try using a different alias than `rank`, since it is a reserved word.

Comment: PARTITION not supported

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.first
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.desc
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col

val dfOrder = df.orderBy(col("id"), col("updateTableTimestamp").desc) 

val dfMax = dfOrder.groupBy(col("id")).
          agg(first("description").as("description"),
              first("name").as("name"),
              first("updateTableTimestamp").as("updateTableTimestamp"))
        dfMax.show
```

[image]

After that, if you want to re-order your fields, just apply a ***select*** function to your new DF.

Comment: Great! Erik Barajas Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Select
Description, name, id, updateTableTimestamp
From table_name
Where id in
(Select  id from table_name group by updateTableTimestamp) order by  updateTableTimestamp desc;